# Split-screen display of multiple Gmail inboxes in one account

Tags: gmail

I just merged my Gmail accounts and am now receiving all the emails in the same inbox while only having to use one account. That's very practical to me right there.

Is it possible to split or show multiple Gmail inboxes or "windows" like having two reception boxes on the same account screen?

I want to be able to see the different inboxes of Gmail accounts that have been merged together in one view.

Comment: more or less.. the second panel is not really a reception box but a "view" on some labels.. ask my question so I can vote for your answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

go to the labs section of gmail (the cog) select `labs`

then find and enable `Multiple Inboxes` this will allow you to create the split display

> Multiple Inboxes by Vivi
>
> Add extra lists of emails in your
>   inbox to see even more important email
>   at once. The new lists of threads can
>   be labels, your starred messages,
>   drafts or any search you want,
>   configurable under Settings

Comment: But does it work when they supposedly have two inboxes streaming to one account? Looks like it's limited to labels on one gmail account.

Comment: "Merged" accounts implies that there is only one Gmail account. I'm not sure what you're asking. The inbox can be defined by a search, such as `to:me@foo.com`.

Comment: @Eight Days of Malaise, thanks for edit.. My question is more clear.. @Matt Multiple inboxes is the solution I use for now. But It is not showing two reception boxes, but just a view on labels..

Comment: @Al Everett thanks, so i think it is not possible too.

Comment: @ bAN you could always use multi sign in if the two accounts where separate allowing you to have the inbox of each account in a different tab

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Gmail multi-inbox option as explained by Lifehacker, [Use Gmail’s Multiple Inboxes Feature to Manage Multiple Addresses](http://lifehacker.com/5157825/use-gmails-multiple-inboxes-feature-to-manage-multiple-addresses).

I understand this is only a "view" but I don't know any way to have the windows split but act like multiple inboxes.

Besides, you can now access two Gmail accounts with the same browser as described on the Official Gmail Blog,  [Access two Gmail accounts at once in the same browser](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/access-two-gmail-accounts-at-once-in.html). Hence, you could have two "tabs" in your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Use Gmail mobile app to achieve this. In the app, you can add and login to multiple accounts. Then you can see emails from all accounts in a single page by selecting the "All Inboxes from the main menu"